# Stack OverflowのQ&AデータにアクセスできるAPIはありますか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, api, data-explorer, data-dump

- Q&Aデータをテキストマイニングしたり
- ユーザーの行動傾向を分析したり
- 専用アプリを作ったり

したいです。何らかのAPIが用意されていたりしますか？

← [FAQに戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 7):

RESTなAPIと、T-SQLでクエリが書けるインタフェース「Stack Exchange Data Explorer」、XML形式のデータダンプが用意されています。

### API

URL: http://api.stackexchange.com/

リアルタイムなデータが取得できます。公式モバイルアプリの機能はほぼ全て、この公開APIをベースに作られています。

- 質問の読み書き
- 回答の読み書き
- コメントの読み書き
- 投票
- バッジ・権限情報
- 検索
- タグ情報
- ユーザー情報

### SEDE: Stack Exchange Data Explorer

URL: http://data.stackexchange.com/

こちらのデータは週に1回の更新です。質問・回答・コメント・投票・各種履歴・ユーザー・バッジ情報に対してT-SQLクエリを書いて実行できます。また以下の機能を備えています。

- パラメータ指定:

  - `##ParameterName:type?default##` という形式でパラメータの値を埋め込みたい場所に記述します
  - クエリの実行時にHTMLフォームでパラメータの値を指定できるようになります
- 自動リンク

  - 以下のエイリアスで`SELECT`すると、実行結果のテーブル内でそれぞれ投稿、ユーザー、コメント、編集リクエストへのリンクとして出力されます
  - `AS [Post Link]`
  - `AS [User Link]`
  - `AS [Comment Link]`
  - `AS [Suggested Edit Link]`
- グラフ表示: 以下のデータ型の並びでSELECTすると、実行結果をグラフで描画してくれます

  - number, number
  - date, number
  - number, string, number
  - date, string, number

サイトのソースコードは[GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer)で公開されています。

### デーダダンプ

URL: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

四半期ごとぐらいに更新されている、XML形式のデーダダンプです。