# stack overflowの公開データについて利用法やデータ詳細やどのような形で提供されているか等を教えていただきたい（API以外の方法も希望する）

Tags: サポート, api, data-explorer, data-dump

stack overflowの公開データについて質問です。
利用法やデータ詳細やどのような形で提供されているか等を教えていただきたい（API以外の方法も希望する）。
また、使用するデータは日本語よりも英語版を希望します。

例えば、
アーカイブデータを提供しているサイトはどういったものなのか。
そのデータを使うために何をする必要があるのか。またその具体的な操作手順はどうすればよいのか。
取得できるデータには規制があるのか。
ベストアンサーが付いた質問文の取得にはどうすればよいか。また件数も調べることも可能か。
回答が付いていない質問文の取得にはどうすればよいか。また件数も調べることも可能か。

アーカイブデータよりAPIの方が良いのであれば、どんなところが良いのかまたはどう扱いやすいかを教えていただきたいとともにAPIも同様に上記の例で挙げたようなことをするためにはどうすればよいのかを教えてください。

以上のようなことについてできるだけ詳しく教えてください。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange では以下のような形式でデータを提供しています。

- [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) - 公式のモバイルアプリでも利用されています。ログインすれば投稿等も可能です
- [SEDE(Stack Exchange Data Explorer)](http://data.stackexchange.com/) - 週1回更新。Web上でT-SQLのクエリを投げられます
- [XMLダンプ](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) - 年4回程度。単独ダウンロード可能なreadme.txtにスキーマが書かれています。

参考 [Stack OverflowのQ&AデータにアクセスできるAPIはありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1621/8000)

取得できるデータは当然のことながら公開情報に限られます。そのため、ユーザーの個人情報、削除済みの投稿、誰が投票したかといった情報はいずれの方法でも取り出せません。またXMLダンプについてはデータサイズの都合もあり、SEDEと比べても[データが削られている](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260790/286934)ようです。

それぞれの解説をまとめて書くと長くなってしまいますから、必要であれば個別に質問してください。また Stack Exchange API、T-SQL、XML処理に関する技術的な質問は、（メタでない）スタックオーバーフローで尋ねてもいいと思います。

> ベストアンサーが付いた質問文の取得にはどうすればよいか。また件数も調べることも可能か。
>   回答が付いていない質問文の取得にはどうすればよいか。また件数も調べることも可能か。

そのような作業を単発で行いたいのなら、抽出・集計の機能を持たないAPIではリクエスト数が増えますし、巨大なXMLダンプをわざわざダウンロードしてDBに突っ込むのも面倒です。そう考えると、既に用意されているDBにクエリを投げるだけで済むSEDEが簡単でしょう。

例 http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/345832

SEDEでアクセス可能なテーブルのスキーマは[編集画面](http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/new)の右側で閲覧できるほか、[メタSEでも説明が書かれています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/286934)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
「APIではリクエスト数が増えますし、巨大なXMLダンプをわざわざダウンロードしてDBに突っ込むのも面倒です。そう考えると、既に用意されているDBにクエリを投げるだけで済むSEDEが簡単でしょう。」
ということなので、
SEDEを使おうと思います。
そこで、質問があるのですが
SEDEの日本語版はありますか？
日本語版があればその方法を教えてもらえませんか？
また、日本語版と英語版では使用方法は同じですか？

Comment: SEDEで日本語版スタックオーバーフローのデータにアクセスすることは可能ですが、残念ながらSEDE自体の日本語版はありません。

Comment: 分かりました。
既に用意されているDBにクエリを投げる方法を上記のURLを参考にしているのですが、苦戦しています。
なので、具体的なSEDEのアクセス法やDBにクエリを投げるまでに必要なことをメタでないスタックオーバーフローの方で質問させていただきます。

Comment: 既に用意されているDBにクエリを投げるにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。
既に用意されているDBの場所
そのDBにクエリを投げる方法
を教えていただいてもよろしいでしょうか。
または参考になるサイトを載せてもらえないでしょうか。
複数サイトを閲覧していたのですが、既に用意されているDBがどんなものなのかわからないという状況です。

Comment: 回答で「編集画面」としてリンクした http://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/new から日本語版SOのDB（のクローン）に対してクエリを投げることができます。または、SEDEの使い方を書いてみようかと考えているので、もうしばらくお待ちください。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。SEDEの使い方を是非お願いします。お待ちしております。お手数ではありますがSEDEの使い方を書かれましたらご報告いただいてもよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: こんな感じでどうでしょうか http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1954/8000