# Stack Exchange Data Explorer の使い方を教えてください

Tags: サポート, よくある質問, data-explorer

以下の「Stack Exchange Data Explorer」というツールで、スタックオーバーフローのデータをT-SQLで参照できると聞きましたが、英語だらけでよくわかりません。どのように操作すればよいのでしょうか？

http://data.stackexchange.com/

関連 [Stack OverflowのQ&AデータにアクセスできるAPIはありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1621/8000)

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

基本的には以下のような流れになります。

1. 対象のサイトを選ぶ
2. 他の人の書いたクエリを探す、もしくは作成
3. 実行

### トップページ

http://data.stackexchange.com/ にアクセスすると次のような画面が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

クエリを実行するには、まずどのサイトのデータを参照するのかを指定する必要があります。Choose a Site にネットワーク内のサイトが並んでいますから、そこで「スタック・オーバーフロー」や「スタック・オーバーフローMeta」を選択します。と、クエリの一覧が現れます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一覧もしくは右上の検索ボックスから、他の人が書いたクエリを探すことができます。もしくは自分でクエリを書く場合は、「Compose Query」をクリックします。

### 編集画面

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

だだっ広いエリアにT-SQLを書いて、下にある「Run Query」で実行します。

どんなテーブル・列が存在するのかは右側の「Database Schema」で調べることができます。Posts、Users といったテーブル名をクリック、もしくは右上の+-ボタンで折りたたむことができます。

PostTypeId に対応する PostTypes などのテーブルは自分で SELECT クエリを書いても構いませんが、 Database Schema 上で「i」アイコンをクリックすることで、一覧を見ることができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 他人のクエリーも見えますので、それも役に立つかもしれません：http://data.stackexchange.com/users/11408/jmac